# Access server context from websockets ws_handler

Tags: python, websocket

I'm writing a simple websocket server application in python using the websockets library.

In my *ws_handler* function I'd like to access some server data.

Here is an imaginary piece of code which expresses what I'm looking for:

```py
async def ws_handler(websocket, path, context):
    await websocket.send("Count={}".format(context.current_count))

some_data = Data()

start_server = websockets.serve(ws_handler, 'localhost', 8765, context=some_data)
```

I'm thinking websockets should have a way to do something like this but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in websockets's cheat sheet documentation: "Passing additional arguments to the connection handler".

Is this case, it would be:

```py
import asyncio
import functools
import websockets

async def ws_handler(websocket, path, context):
    await websocket.send("Count={}".format(context.current_count))

some_data = Data()

bound_handler = functools.partial(ws_handler, context=some_data)
start_server = websockets.serve(bound_handler, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```